# Server application has enabled CORS yet client gets "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, api, cross-domain

I have an `RESTful API` and I've added this to allow Cross-origin request

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        //  Allow Cross-origin request
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors();

        ...
    }
```

My client is an `AngularJS` application calling the server like this

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
                Request: 'INIT'
            }),
            req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:51615/api/Call/2/' + json
            }

        $http(req)
            .then(function(response){
                console.info('response', response)
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
            })
```

Even thou Cross-origin should be allowed I still get this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:51615/api/Call/2/%7B%22Request%22:%22INIT%22%7D. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:86' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

How can this be?

Comment: Check the actual network response to the OPTIONS request in chrome and see what headers are being sent back... if they don't include Access-Control-Allow-Origin figure out why your asp configuration isn't active.  Basically saying there isn't anything to do on the angular side of things here, this is all between the browser and the server :)

Comment: @shaunhusain: should have looked at that before. The problem was that the `json` part of my url was unsafe. Changing the call from a `get` to a `post` with json as data instead fixed it.

Comment: Ah interesting thanks for posting back the actual problem, can probably answer your own question here, I didn't know that could cause this error (TIL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to @shaunhusain for pointing out that I should take a look at the network response in `chrome`. Here I saw that the problem was with unsafe data in my url string (the json part). Changing the request from `get` to `post` along with json as data and not part of the url fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

try with putting this two appsettings in web.config of your web api project

```
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <appSettings>
    </configuration>
```